# Is selling program / liking bot legal?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, internet, software, european-union

Would it be legal to sell a program / bot that log into a website account and like others posts? Is it legal on the assumption that user is responsible for use of that program (getting ban is his fault).

Comment: I think the general idea is that using bots to emulate _people_ is against terms of service at many web sites... and against the general spirit of these things. So you'd be selling something to people to do disapproved things, if not actually illegal. Yes, they might get banned, but not you, ... but why would you want to sell this?

Comment: @paulgarrett So if it's violating TOS that mean this is illegal? What could happen to me and end-user? It's single account liking posts of others. Just it. 
I would like to be clear with end-user.

Answer (score 1):

Various jurisdictions have "hacking tools clauses" to criminalize the production/sale of software for certain purposes, e.g. the [UK](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/computer-misuse-act). You might try to argue that the activity of your software does not constitute hacking, but a simple "blame the user" won't be enough.

Comment: I'm not breaking systems or steal information, so it would not be a hacking tool. It is some sort of automation, but definitely violating the terms of service.

Comment: @PatrykChowratowicz'Zszywacz', making that determination with a non-lawyer's understanding of the terms is extremely risky. If you plan to do that as your business model, hire a specialized lawyer.